# The this is undefined if used inside a debounce function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

For some reason the `this` is undefined if I'm using a debounce function. I have tried to bind it but still it is undefined. I can't understand what is happening here..

For example here `this` is working and returns

> VueComponent {_uid: 6, _isVue: true, $options: {…}, _renderProxy: Proxy, _self: VueComponent, …}

```
<template>
    <at-ta @at="fetchMembers">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </at-ta>  
</template>

fetchMembers(at)
{
    console.log(this) // <-- VueComponent { ...
},
```

But when I move it to a debounce function it isn't working anymore but is

> this is undefined

```
fetchMembers: debounce(at => {
    axios.get(`/api/users?name=${at}`).then(({data}) => {
        this.members = data  // <-- this is undefined
    })
}, 500)
```

Comment: Use a function expression instead of an arrow function. See [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196). And then of course `debounce` must correctly "forward" the value of `this` to the wrapped function.

Comment: Can you please show an example how?

Comment: `fetchMembers: debounce(function(at) { ... }, 500)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bind the debounced function, but do bind the axios promise callback.

```js
methods: {
  fetchMembers: debounce(function (at) {
    axios.get(`/api/users?name=${at}`).then(({data}) => {
      this.members = data
    })
  }, 500)
}
```

It didn't work for you because you used a fat arrow function for the debounced function where `this` is undefined at that scope.

Keep in mind that you're only creating one debounced function that will be shared across all instances of your component. If this is an issue, you can instead wrap `fetchMembers` with a debounced function in the `created` hook:

```
created() {
  this.fetchMembers = _.debounce(this.fetchMembers, 500)
},

methods: {
  fetchMembers() {
    axios.get(`/api/users?name=${at}`).then(({data}) => {
      this.members = data
    })
  }
},
```

Comment: When I switched to using async/await still getting undefined for this

Comment: That's a different issue. You'll have to share your code or ask a new question.

Comment: Actually I really like your approach of creating a debounce function in the ````created()```` hook. Now it even works for ````async/await````.